# get a 'win' in even expriment

Tags: probability, combinatorics

unfair coin give '$x$' in probability $p$ and '$y$' in ($1-p$).
we toss it up until we get '$x$'.
what is the probability that we get '$x$' in even tossing?

I know that for even tossing we need $(1-p)^k*p$ where $k$ is odd.

but how do I get the probability for general even toss?

Comment: Add up over all odd $k$. So we have $(1-p)(p)[1+r+r^2+\cdots]$ where $r=(1-p)^2$. Infinite geometric series.

Comment: is that a legit answer?

Comment: @opeer yes it is legit. Do you know geometric series?

Comment: You would be expected to sum the series explicitly. You probably know the "formula."

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_e$ be the sought probability. To get $x$ in even tossing, we must either get $yx$ in the first two rounds (which happens with probability $(1-p)p$, of course) or we must start with $yy$ and then get $x$ in an even tossing in the *subsequent* rounds, which happens with probability $(1-p)^2\cdot p_e$. All in all we find
$$p_e = (1-p)p+(1-p)^2p_e.$$
Hence 
$$ p_e = \frac{(1-p)p}{1-(1-p)^2}=\frac{1-p}{2-p}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in various ways.

- First toss gives $y$ , second gives $x$
- First, second and third give $y$, fourth gives $x$
- First, second, third , fourth, fifth gives $y$, sixth gives $x$.

Ad infinitum.

So our probability is obtained by summing up infinite number of individual cases.

$$(1-p)p+(1-p)^3p+(1-p)^5p+\cdots$$

Which is,

$$\frac{(1-p)p}{1-(1-p)^2} = \frac{(1-p)p}{1-1+2p-p^2}=\frac{1-p}{2-p}$$

---

In case you aren't aware of the series,

$$S=1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^n$$

$$rS= r+r^2+\cdots r^n$$

$$S=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

Take $\lim_{n\to\infty}S$ with $|r|\lt1$

Comment: but now i have 2 answers which are not the same..

Comment: @opeer I am checking mine. I don't think there is any mistake here.

Comment: @opeer As far as I can tell this is correctt.

Comment: @opeer update. I found the mistake.

Comment: great, thank you so much for your help